# senderName - Programmatically setting senderName

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to set senderName programmatically for different recipients.  My envelope has two recipients and a) for one of the recipient, I want the senderName to be my company and b) for another recipient, I would want to set it just before sending envelope programmatically.  I think a) can be solved by updating the account name of the docusign Owner.

How can I achieve result b)?

Thanks

Comment: If i'm understanding your question correctly, you would like to have 1 envelope with '2 different senders, depending on the recipient'.. I'm fairly confident this is not possible. I believe the envelope:sender ration is 1:1. A workaround would be to set the NOTE field which is recipient specific and put some recipient specific language in there. The sender would need to be generic/relevant across both recipients.

Comment: Thats right.  2 different senders depending on the recipient.  The situation is my customer's customer would not want to see my company name if they are dealing directly with my customer.  But a single envelop is sent by my company to both of them.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done for a single envelope.

You could do that by sending two envelopes, but a single envelope in DocuSign has a single sender, which means all recipients in the same envelope would have the same senderName and you cannot have it differently for each one.